Can PlayStore Intefer with DataFlow of the Apps that are hosted in it?
I was wondering, We host our applications on Google PlayStore. Are there any possibilities that PlayStore can interfer with the DataFlow of the Application? You see Google never reveals anything, lol. But is that possible even if we write the safest/robust APIs with all the strong Authentication and Authorisation practices?
This might be a dumbest question, I am a newbie.
I searched in several websites but couldn't get a precise answer. I tried using chatGpt but its kinda favourable to Google. I am expecting a realtime example someone might have faced or any precise answer.
